# Get $this in method protected boot model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code on My Model:

```
 protected static function boot() {
      parent::boot();

      if($this->status == 1) {
         static::updated(function () {
            //do something
         }
      }
 }
```

I need check if status of current record == 1 then do `static::updated()`.
Now I get error: $this cannot be in static function.

How I can check status in protected static function boot?

Comment: That's not possible because static functions are independent of any instantiated object.

Comment: Do you really need it to be static?

Comment: Static functions can't recognize $this as it is an instantiated object as @Daan said. All you can try is to either get it in the parameter or try to return it from some function from the parent. so in your static function, you can get it like `$status = parent::SomeFunctionThatReturnsStatus();` and you can then use $status in your `if` condition

Comment: Also can you please tell why do you need to make it a static function ?

Answer (score 2):

Like Daan mentioned in the comments this is not possible, you could however solve this in another way:

```php
protected static function boot() {
      parent::boot();

      static::updated(function ($model) {
          if ($model->status == 1) {
              //do something
          }
      });
 }
```

Comment: I already mentioned to use some other function to get the variable $status as a function parameter and then use it in this static function.

Answer (score 0):

## 1) Usage of `$this`

You should replace `$this` with `self::` to refer to the variable (`$status`) contained within the static class:

```
 protected static function boot() {
      parent::boot();

      if(self::$_status == 1) {
         static::updated(function () {
            //do something
         }); //also close off your method call correctly.
      }
 }
```

## 2) Check if status of current record = 1

> I need check if status of current record == 1 then do static::updated().

Where is the value of `$status` set/saved/accessible? The code you show appears to show that `$status` is set in the class itself, but as a static class this will be, er, static.

You may need to stop the class/method being static **or** to supply the data to the function like so:

```
 protected static function boot($status = null) {
      parent::boot();

      if($status == 1) {
         static::updated(function () {
            //do something
         }); // close off your method properly.
      }
 }
```

Comment: The second case that you mentioned, is what i already told @Dronax, i.e. to get the variable $status as a function parameter. :}

Comment: @Dronax yes, but how does PHP get this informtion?